# Apache AGE - Return nodes having a property with common pattern

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age, opencypher

Here I have two nodes with the property 'name' that contains the first name and last name of a person. I create the vertices as:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
CREATE (n:Person {name : "Michael Stone", age : 20}), (m: Person {name : "Michael Douglas", age: 19})  
RETURN n, m
$$) AS (n agtype, m agtype);
```

I want to retrieve the nodes where the first name is Michael. How can it be done? Is there any clause such as "LIKE" (as in postgreqsl) in AGE?

Answer (score 1):

**LIKE** operator is not supported by AGE yet.

There are **two** operators which might help you.

1. ***CONTAINS***
2. ***STARTS WITH***

   ```
   MATCH (n:Person)
   WHERE n.name STARTS WITH / CONTAINS "Michael"
   RETURN n
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As AGE does not support `Like` clause in Cypher, However you can use the `=~` operator with a regular expression to achieve similar functionality.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.first_name =~ '.*Micheal.*' Return n
```

This query will returns all nodes whose first name contains the substring "Micheal".

```
MATCH (n) WHERE substring(n.first_name, 0 , 7) = 'Micheal' Return n
```

To retrieve node where the first name is Micheal, you can use this query in Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression matching to find a substring within a string. In your case, it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (v:Person)
    WHERE v.name =~ 'Michael.*'
    RETURN v
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

Note that the '.' operator is a wildcard and matches against any possible character, while the '*' operator matches with 0 or more of the previous character (in this case it can be 0 or more of any possible character).

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to retrieve the nodes where the first name is Michael, is through following query.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE split(n.name, ' ')[0] = 'Michael'
RETURN n
$$) AS (n agtype);
```

Here in the query the MATCH clause is used to find all the node labeled as 'Person', WHERE clause is used to filter the results based on the first name of the person then the split function is called to split the name property based on the space delimiter and retrieve the first element of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to return the nodes with name starting with `Micheal`.

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name ~ '^Michael'
RETURN n;
```

Here  `~` is used for regular expression matching because `LIKE` is not supported in AGE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex for the purpose and also for other more complicated patterns.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ '^Michale\b.*'
RETURN n
$$) AS (n agtype);
```

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `Michale` matches the literal word Michale
- `\b` matches a word boundary, so that Michale is not part of a longer
  word
- `.*` matches any characters until the end of the string

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use like operator like this

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name LIKE 'Michael%'
RETURN p
```

To get all the names starting with Michael as first name.

Comment: No, This throws an error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIKE"`.